# Problema com Filter do CSS em alguns navegadores

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando usar o parametro `filter` do CSS, mas em alguns navegadores com o Chrome e IE não está funcionando, já no firefox ele funciona normalmente como o desejado. O código que tenho é esse:

```
.empresas-marcas ul li a{
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(1000%) opacity(30%);
-moz-filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(100%) opacity(30%);
-ms-filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(100%) opacity(30%);
-o-filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(100%) opacity(30%);
filter:grayscale(100%) contrast(100%) opacity(30%);
-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.empresas-marcas ul li a:hover{
-webkit-filter:grayscale(0);
-moz-filter:grayscale(0);
-ms-filter:grayscale(0);
-o-filter:grayscale(0);
filter:grayscale(0);
-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
transition:all 300ms ease-in-out
}
```

Esse código deixa a imagem preto e branco e quando passo o mouse sobre a imagem ela fica colorida.

Não sei se tem que adicionar algum javascript auxilar para fazer funcionar, mas precisava arrumar isso urgentemente.

Comment: Há um erro no seu código. Tem um 1000% na segunda linha.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o site [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), a propriedade filter do css só é suportada no edge, não no Internet Explorer.
Além disso, há um errona segunda linha do seu arquivo. Um 1000% que deveria ser 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Para aplicar a transição a um "filter" corretamente, você deve passar o novo valor de todos os filtros que foram aplicados e não somente do que deseja alterar.

Por exemplo:

```
a {

    filter: hue-rotate(45deg) brightness(1.5);

}

a:hover {

    filter: hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(1);

}
```